# SQL Query succeeds but no information

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay so my code works pretty well so far, it all goes through, my only problem is that when I try and print the unordered list and it's contents I get nothing. When I view my source code I have `<ul> </ul>`. There's a space, so surely something is happening.

This is my code, I have commented it slightly but what's happening is obvious:

```
$uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_SESSION['Username']); //Get username ready
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '" . $uname . "'"); //SQL Query result

    if(!$sql)
        {
        echo "Error retrieving User ID. Please try again. MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    elseif($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
            $uid = $row['UserID']; //Obtain UserID
        }
    else
        {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($link) . "<br />" . $uname . " / " . $sql . " / " . $uid;
        }

    mysqli_free_result($sql);

    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM auditions"); //Get everything from the auditions table

    if(!$sql)
        {
        echo "Error retrieving auditions. Please try again later. Error: " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
    elseif($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0)
            {
            echo "Sorry, there are currently no open auditions. Please try back at a later date.";
            }
        else
            {
            echo "<ul>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
                {
                echo "<li><a href='auditions.php?id=" . $row['AudID'] . "'>" . $row['AudName'] . "</a></li>";
                }
            echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
    else
        {
        echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
```

Where am I going wrong? The only thing it doesn't do is actually pick up any results and I've put some data into the table so there are entries! Otherwise it would say there aren't any. I've reversed this so it shows the message if there aren't 0 entries and that works. What am I doing wrong guys?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching the result twice. Instead, only fetch the result in the `while` loop:

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM auditions"); //Get everything from the auditions table

    if(!$sql)
        {
            echo "Error retrieving auditions. Please try again later. Error: " . mysqli_error($link);
        }
        else{
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0)
            {
                echo "Sorry, there are currently no open auditions. Please try back at a later date.";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<ul>";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
                {
                    echo "<li><a href='auditions.php?id=" . $row['AudID'] . "'>" . $row['AudName'] . "</a></li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }

?>
```

[See this link for more information regarding mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: @user2195574 I can't guarantee that my answer solves your problem as there may be a lot more to it. However, that is definitely an issue I see with your code so please let me know if it works / helps you out.